# How to handle caching on a Drupal 8 custom Views access plugin that checks a User's Profile's field value

Tags: 8, views

I have a custom Views access plugin that check access against a value in the current User's Profile (entity) field value.

The plugin works but if I change the profile field value the access does not check again until the cache is cleared. I know this is an issue with setting up the cache tags/contexts but I cannot not figure out what is needed so that the cache is cleared when the user profile is updated.

Right now I'm not using any cache tags/contexts in my View access plug and I've tried various combinations without luck. Help!

Current cache functions:

```
public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return Cache::PERMANENT;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheContexts() {
    return ['user'];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheTags() {
    $profile = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('profile')->loadByUser(user_load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id()), 'employee');    
return $profile->getCacheTags();
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

A Views access plugin implements [CacheableDependencyInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cache%21CacheableDependencyInterface.php/interface/CacheableDependencyInterface/8.4.x). So you probably need to set a tag and a context for the current user in these methods:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return Cache::PERMANENT;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheContexts() {
    return ['user'];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheTags() {
    return ['user:' . \Drupal::currentUser()->id()];
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not adding the current user ID to getCacheTags - makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. The caching is still not clearing properly. The cache tags example you provided is using the user object but the field value that I am changing is on the Profile object for the user. Is there a way to set the cache contexts to use the Profile object of the user?

Comment: I've supposed you mean with user profile the core user entity, because core often refers to the user content form as profile, but if this is from a contrib module, then load the profile entity the same like you did for the field value and return the cache tag from this entity `$profile->getCacheTags()`. This is only for the tag, the context is still a dependency on the current user.

Comment: Thanks again. I still can't get it to work. And, yes, sorry, by profile I was referring to the contrib profile module that creates 'profile' entities for the user objects. I've edited my original question to include my current cache functions. I am loading the profile entity in getCacheTags() and returning it as return $profile->getCacheTags() - the getCacheContexts() is set to return ['user']

Comment: How would this work for anon user. For example, test a language variable...